# Get Value of String Class Attribute

Tags: java, weka

I need to iterate over all (String) classes of a dataset as well as the class-value of each instance.

While `Attribute.enumerateValues()` gives - as wanted - the collection of the "raw"-Values, I can not obtain the raw-value of the class of a single instance as `Instance.classValue()`

> Returns:
>       the corresponding value as a double (If the corresponding attribute is nominal (or a string) then it returns the value's index as a double).

How can I get the String-Value of the class attribute of a certain instance?

EDIT A solution might be to build a look-up table so you have "class-value-String<-->corresponding index".. But i don't know in which order the indices are generated.. But I do not know the order in which weka generates the index. So that might risk a bug. 
A linked question may be how WEKA is treating String-Attributes. As many classifiers can not hanndle Strings, at some point the Strings seem to be converted into distinct doubles.. But they are not nominal-class..

Answer (score 0):

It was easy (shame on me)..

```
Instance.stringValue(Attribute)
```

Gives the needed value..

Still confusing and I did not expect that, as the *Value* returned by `Instances.classValue()` is a `double`..

Comment: Well it was easy. Glad you found it. `Instance.classValue()` returns String to me though.